TypeError: getData.map is not a function
This my backend API using expressjs
      res.json({
        data: users,
        message: "Successfully fetched users",
        status: 200,
      });

Fetching in nextjs TypeScript
const [getData, setGetData] = useState<User[]>([]);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get<User[]>("http://localhost:3001/users");
      setGetData(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

Mapping In Frontend Nextjs Typescript
<TableBody>
        {getData.map((user, i) => (
          <TableRow key={user.data.id}>
            <TableCell className="font-medium">{i + 1}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{user.data.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{user.data.phone}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{user.data.createdAt.toString()}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="flex items-center justify-center">
              <Button
                variant="default"
                className="mr-1">
                Edit
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="destructive"
                className="ml-1">
                Delete
              </Button>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>

i got error like this TypeError: getData.map is not a function i don't how to fix it anyone can help me to fix it

What is the out put of this console.log(res.data); .It seems that thre is a state where getData is not an Array
